# Implement RadioButtonFor in mvc 4 Gender

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, data-binding, simplemembership, radiobuttonfor

i want to implement radiobuttonfor in Simple Membership Provider.

My codes are as follow

Account Model:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "IsMale")]
public bool IsMale { get; set; }
```

View :

```
<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsMale)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsMale, "Male", Model.IsMale == true ? new { Checked = "checked"} : null ) Male
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsMale, "Female", Model.IsMale == false ? new { Checked = "checked"} : null) Female
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsMale)
        </div>
```

i am having error message : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

can anyone please help out.

Comment: You property `IsMale` is a `boolean` so the 2nd parameters of `RadioButtonFor()` should be "True" and "False" (not "Male" and "Female")

Answer (score 0):

try this-->

```
private bool _IsMale = false;    

[Required]
[Display(Name = "IsMale")]
public bool IsMale { 
get { return _IsMale ; }
set { _IsMale = value; } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I successfully did it through these changes :

Account Model:

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Gender")]
    public bool Gender { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<div class ="editor-field">
        @Html.RadioButton("Gender", true, true) Male
        @Html.RadioButton("Gender", false, false) Female

    </div>
```

In the database either true or false is saved for male and female respectively. I suppose if can easily be converted to Male or Female if required by changing the type for gender field to string and change second argument for Radiobutton to Male and Female.

Thanks for alternatives you provided.